# where to put time format rules in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I am finding myself repeating typing many strftime which I defined.

Having watch Ryan Bates's railscasts ep 32/33( I think), I created a custom option for the to_s method as in Time.now.to_s, so that I can do Time.now.to_s(:sw), where :sw is my custom method, to retrieve "23 Sep 2010, 5:00PM" for example.

But the problem is, I don't know where to put #sw's definition. Should it be in a file in in the initializer folder? Or should it go in application.rb?

Thanks!

Comment: BTW http://strftime.net/ helps a lot

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have a file `config/initialisers/time_formats.rb` containing:

```
...
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:posts] = "%B %d, %Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:published] = "%B %Y"
...
```

You just need to restart your server to have the changes picked up.

Comment: Okay, I thought so, too.Also because that way, you get to organize these 'helpers' in files rather than in lines in the application.rb Thanks!

Answer (score 45):

Use "time" instead of "date" in your locales file, since Rails timestamps are datetimes.

in **config/locales/en.yml**

```
en:
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%Y/%m/%d"
      short: "%b %d"
      long: "%B %d, %Y"
```

in **app/views/posts/show.html.haml**

```
  = l post.updated_at
  = l post.created_at, :format => :long
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Rails I18n API.

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%Y-%m-%d"
      short: "%b %d"
      long: "%B %d, %Y"

# in views 
= l post.updated_at # will use default format of date in locales yml file
```

see about [I18n API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats)

Answer (score 0):

Please read this post:

[Rails - to_formatted_s](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/DateTime/Conversions/to_formatted_s)

Create file with name: config/initializers/time_formats.rb

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:my_custom_time_format] = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
```

And you can use:

```
formated_date = my_date.to_formatted_s(:my_custom_time_format)
```

**Note: You must to restart your rails server (WEBRick, FCGI, etc)**

Comment: Ah, I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why my formats were not changing. Thanks for the server restart tip!