# strftime formatting with Ruby/Rails -- Lowercase am/pm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, strftime

I have the following:

```
@comment.created_at.strftime("%I:%M %p %b %d")
```

Which outputs: 10:32 AM Dec 19

I'd like to output a lowercase am, like: 10:32am Dec 19

Any ideas on how to do that with ruby/rails?

thanks

Answer (score 10):

Try to use %P instead using %p

Answer (score 2):

Use %P instead of %p. That'll work with ruby 1.9 but for 1.8 you'll need to use `.sub(' AM ', ' am ').sub(' PM ', ' pm ')` or similar.

Comment: Interesting. I'm on Heroku, not sure which version or ruby is used.

Comment: `<%= RUBY_VERSION %>` should give you a hint ;-)

Comment: The ruby 1.9 v on Heroku are all betas, so I'd like to avoid that for now.

Answer (score 2):

You may save them into different vars and do somthing like:

```
a = @comment.created_at.strftime("%I:%M")
b = @comment.created_at.strftime("%P").downcase
c = @comment.created_at.strftime("%b %d")

e = a+b+" "+c #=> 10:32am Dec 19
```

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694352/rails-3-default-datetime-format-without-utc) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654974/where-to-put-time-format-rules-in-rails-3) should give you what you need. YOu basically define a custom Time format within in the initializers.

If you want to have it from the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html), they show what the defaults are in the Time class

Comment: Why is this answer upvoted? It's totally missing the point of the question ?;-)

Answer (score 1):

it seems that in ruby 1.9 you can use %P instead of %p and don't forget to remove a space

> @comment.created_at.strftime("%I:%M%P %b %d")
>   =>10:32am Dec 19