# Ruby on rails date formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, format, haml

I am trying to format my date from my RoR project, though having real issue understanding how this works. In php this is a simple date("format",time())

if i call just the standard time stored within the database i am getting
`2012-08-12 22:25:00 +1000`

I am trying to call the date formats event_time and event_date

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:month_and_year] = "%B %Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:event_time] = "%l:%M %p"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:event_date] = "%a, %e %b, %Y"
```

I am currently trying to call this like

```
= schedule.time.to_s(:event_time)
```

The issue I am having is that I am getting the following error:

> > wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)

Comment: to_s wont accept any parameter so that error is there, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654974/where-to-put-time-format-rules-in-rails-3), [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html) and [this](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/42-use-i18n-localize-for-date-time-formating)

Comment: have already read those pages, and have place my formats within `# config/initializers/time_formats.rb` this was how they have always been defined, though it doesnt appear to work

Comment: is your schedule.time a date/time object i think it may be string

Comment: its timestamp `time             | timestamp without time zone | 
`

Comment: what is output of schedule.time.to_s

Comment: output of schedule.time.to_s is `2012-08-12 22:25:00 +1000`

Comment: everything seems to be fine here , one silly question which i encountered while testing is there .. before `to_s` like `schedule.time..to_s(:event_time)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use strftime  or esle your approach is also good if you need data frequently  in this date format

The code you added works great for me

```
pritesh@cloudy-pritesh:~/railsdemo$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.6)
1.9.3p194 :001 > Date.today.to_s(:event_time)
 => "2012-08-13" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > Time::DATE_FORMATS[:month_and_year] = "%B %Y"
 => "%B %Y" 
1.9.3p194 :003 > Time::DATE_FORMATS[:event_time] = "%l:%M %p"
 => "%l:%M %p" 
1.9.3p194 :004 > Time::DATE_FORMATS[:event_date] = "%a, %e %b, %Y"
 => "%a, %e %b, %Y" 
1.9.3p194 :005 > Time.now.to_s(:event_time)
 => "11:13 AM"
```

you can also do this by  using `Time.now.strftime("%B %Y")`

My last guess, may be you are looping the records and shomewhere in the records there is a record with time having nil value

Comment: problem is that it isnt working for me, or if i use schedule.time.strftime("%B %Y") im getting a nil class, these formats worked when we had the data stored within the db as a string, since changing to timestamp so we can could do time comparisons these formats have stopped

Comment: the above worked for me with psql too may be i think your data format might have broken while column type change

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane, My last may be you are looping the records and shomewhere in the records there is a record with time nil value

Comment: totally correct there was a nil within the loop, ill need to ensure there is some validation so my users cannot add without a time being entered

Comment: The Time.now.strftime("%B %Y") really helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [strftime](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime)

```
Time.now.strftime("%B %Y")   #August 2012
```

Then use something like following

```
Time.now.strftime(Time::DATE_FORMATS[:month_and_year])
```

Comment: im using strftime within my date formats file, i need to be able to call those formats around what is stored in the database

Comment: i need to reference back to the timestamp store in the database, this doesnt seem to be a correct method

Answer (score 0):

Its simple,

```
schedule.time.strftime(Time::DATE_FORMATS[:format_type])   #August 2012
```

refer http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime for detailed use.

Comment: that gives me the following `undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: what is the name of the field where time info is stored? make that `field_name.srtftime(....)`

Comment: the name is time, should i maybe call it something else?

Comment: That may not be the problem. Check for the value of `time` in the database, since you are getting NilClass error. Also check the fieldtype.