# ruby-american_date gem still displays yyyy-mm-dd in text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added the following line in Gemfile.

gem 'american_date'

Rails is 3.2.13 and ruby is 1.9.3.

Everything's fine except that text field shows yyyy-mm-dd format instead of mm/dd/yyyy.

How do I set it correctly?

Sam

Edit:

I have the following configuration in the initializer.

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(default: "%m/%d/%Y")
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(default: "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

However, the text field is not using the format. Why don't know why.

Comment: The `american_date` gem is only for parsing dates (i.e. from strings), not displaying them (i.e. to strings).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [a custom Time formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654974/where-to-put-time-format-rules-in-rails-3)? You don't need a whole gem to output mm/dd/yyyy format for a Time object.

Comment: I forgot to mention the configuration. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using jQuery.
I put the code inside of ready event.

```
  $('input.date').each(function() {
    if (/\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d/.test(this.value)) {
      var d = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd",  this.value);
      this.value = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', d);
    }
  })
```